# Split router logic into separate functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

I have a get request handler of a Router in Node.js and it has
a lot of code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


router.get("/api/employees/employee-response", async (req, res) => {
  try {

     // First action with code 

     // Second action with code 

     // Third action with code 

  }


catch(exp) {

  // ...
}



module.exports = router;
```

How can I split that into small functions and call those functions from the Router?